# ruamel.yaml: Trying to parse a GitHub Actions workflow file, do some modifications to it and then dump back to file. Formatting is off/unexpected

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am using Python to migrate our GitHub Actions workflows.

Chose ruamel.yaml over pyYaml because here I at least have the option to preserve quotes.

Now, it looks like this though:

```yaml
 - {uses: actions/checkout@v3}
```

The original is this:

```
 - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

This is not consistent though. Sometimes the original formatting (without braces) is kept.

Any way to avoid formatting with braces?

And while we are at it:

```
run: |
  sed -i "/$IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND@sha256/c frontendImage: $IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND@$IMAGE_DIGEST_FRONTEND" it/k8s/admin/values.yaml
```

Is it possible to keep this formatting as well somehow? Because right now it does this:

```
 - {name: Register RepoDigests, run: "sed -i \"/$IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND@sha256/c\ frontendImage: $IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND@$IMAGE_DIGEST_FRONTEND\" it/k8s/admin/values.yaml\n",
```

I mean, is there a way to keep the `|` for multiline strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not very informative, so it is difficult to see what you are doing (or possible do wrong). `ruamel.yaml` in the default
round-trip mode, will however preserve flow-style/block-style and also the block literal-style scalars ( introduced by `|`):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
abc:
 - {uses: actions/checkout@v3}
 - uses: actions/checkout@v3
 - name: Register RepoDigests
   run: |
     sed -i "/$IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND@sha256/c frontendImage: $IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND@$IMAGE_DIGEST_FRONTEND" it/k8s/admin/values.yaml
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
abc:
- {uses: actions/checkout@v3}
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Register RepoDigests
  run: |
    sed -i "/$IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND@sha256/c frontendImage: $IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND@$IMAGE_DIGEST_FRONTEND" it/k8s/admin/values.yaml
```

If you add to `data`, then by default block-style will be taken (i.e. without braces), unless you did

```
yaml.default_flow_style = None  # or True
```

You can change the value for key `run` (i.e. the sed commandline), but you have to take care. That
value prints like a string, and behaves like a string, and you can e.g. do a `.replace()`. but it
is not a normal Python string, instead it is a `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralStyleScalar`, and its type
information is what is used to dump the whole thing again as a literal style scalar. So
you might need to "preserve" the type if you assign a new value to the key `run`:

```py
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['abc'].append(dict(extra='read all about it'))
x = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap(some='more')
x.fa.set_flow_style()  # fa for FlowAttribute
rundata = data['abc'][2]
lit_style = type(rundata['run'])
rundata['run'] = rundata['run'].replace('sha256', 'sha512')
rundata['post'] = lit_style('rm -f *.junk')
data['abc'].append(x)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
abc:
- {uses: actions/checkout@v3}
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Register RepoDigests
  run: |
    sed -i "/$IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND@sha512/c frontendImage: $IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND@$IMAGE_DIGEST_FRONTEND" it/k8s/admin/values.yaml
  post: |-
    rm -f *.junk
- extra: read all about it
- {some: more}
```